# mysql 'Rlike' not working properly

Tags: mysql

I am using MYSQL RLIKE in below query:

```
SELECT
filtering_table_data.Model,
case when filtering_table_data.Model  
  RLIKE '^[ETS 2229]' OR '^[F 202]' then 'valid Model' else 'Invalid Model'  end 
  AS Model_Status 
FROM
filtering_table_data
```

but it gives some wrong outputs in the query results:

[image]

I didn't include any regular expression for the model 'ETS2221' but it gives the output as a valid Model.

Model field is varchar

Comment: Your `^[ETS 2229]` pattern makes no sense to me: it requires that the first character is either an `E`, a `T`, a `S`, a space, a `2`, a `2`, a `2` or a `9`...

Comment: Also `OR 'string'` do not seem to be a very logical (part of) expression...

Comment: Sorry i may be wrong, but how can i use mysql case to get the above mentioned output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT Model,
       CASE WHEN Model RLIKE '^(ETS 2229|F 202)' THEN 'valid Model '
                                                 ELSE 'Invalid Model' AND AS Model_Status 
FROM filtering_table_data
```

See [MySQL Reference Manual / Regular Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

Comment: got it thank you very much, is there any possibility to check the null/empty data using another else if,

Comment: Just insert another `WHEN ... THEN ...` line(s) before the `ELSE` line...